# Problem with error about model being passed into partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So I am trying to render a partial view into my page and I am getting the below error:

**ERROR**

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 
'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[GettingOrganized.Models.Todo]', but this 
dictionary requires a model item of type 'GettingOrganized.Models.Todo'.
```

I don't see what is wrong with the partial view or controller.

**PARTIAL VIEW**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<GettingOrganized.Models.Todo>" %> 
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Todo", FormMethod.Post, new {id="CreateTodo"})) {%>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title) %>
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

<% } %>
```

Controller Index View that Renders the Partial View:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("CreateElements"); %>
```

Any thoughts?  I would like to keep it as close to this setup since is strong typed.

**UPDATE**

So to provide a few more details, now that problem is becoming more clear.  I am rendering the view on the page in a div and hiding it the user clicks a certain link.  Then I want to show the div.  This same partial is used in a "Create" view where you can create a "Todo".  But I am now wanting to use the partial in the Index view which shows a list of the model "Todo".

The model passed in, in the "Index" view:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<GettingOrganized.Models.Todo>>" %>
```

So if I don't want to loop through a foreach loop, and just want to show one instance of the model, who do I do that?

Also I can use the following view for the partial and it will work which takes away the strongly typed to the model:

**WORKING PARTIAL**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %> 
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Todo", 
FormMethod.Post, new { id="CreateTodo"})) {%>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Fields</legend>
    <p>
        <label for="Title">Title:</label>
        <%=Html.TextBox("Title")%>
        <%=Html.ValidationMessage("Title", "*")%>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Create" />
</p>
<% } %>
```

**Possible Answer**

However, I believe I might have found an answer.

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("CreateElements", new Todo()); %>
```

Is this a proper way to handle this?

Comment: whats the model for the Index View?

Comment: I updated - under "UPDATED" with the model and more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However, I believe I might have found an answer.

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("CreateElements", new Todo()); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to pass the model to the partial view - as in:

```
 <% Html.RenderPartial("CreateElements", myModel); %>
```

Comment: Dang! I can't edit - I'm stuck on IE6 at work half the JS on this site doesn't work with it :( here was what I was going to edit with: On second thought... Maybe the original model is passed to the Partial by default (can't develop asp.net from where I am to test). In that case, I'd bet that you need to take your linq expression and add .FirstOrDefault() at the end - to return only one item rather than the collection you're currently using for your model.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into how you're passing in your model into the RenderPartial:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("CreateElements", model); %>
```

And make sure that model is of type GettingOrganized.Models.Todo.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not passing a model into your RenderPartial call, MVC is effectively trying to create one for you using the ViewDataDictionary and model from the parent page.

It looks like the parent page has a model type which is a List of ToDo items, so I guess you can just call your RenderPartial method inside of a loop; something along the lines of:

```
<% foreach (GettingOrganized.Models.Todo todoItem in Model) {
    Html.RenderPartial("CreateElements", todoItem);
} %>
```